# How to arrange HTML Widgets inside of a RMarkdown Document (PDF, HTML)

Tags: r, leaflet, knitr, r-markdown, htmlwidgets

I'm working in a [R notebook](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html) and would like use it to create two ouptuts: an HTML document and PDF document.

My analysis includes leaflet maps (html widgets), which is **causing problems when I knit the notebook to a PDF document**. Thanks to the [`webshot`](https://github.com/wch/webshot) function now included in the `knitr` package, "knitr will try to generate static screenshots for HTML widgets automatically using the webshot package" (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md).

This works fine when my output is a series of leaflet maps stacked on top of each other, but I would like to group the maps together in a more concise row arrangement (see image below).

[image: screenshot]

Here's a reproducible example of my R notebook: [gist](https://gist.github.com/tiernanmartin/0fd957e0a22cfa533886c35b8a2e9e0d)

Unfortunately, when I try to knit this to a PDF document I get the following error message:

```
Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: yes

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.
```

How can I get this single-row arrangement in a PDF document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then all you have to do is to add some chunk options. The key here is the option `fig.show='hold'` which determines that all plots in the chunk will be *collected* and displayed together at the very end of the chunk.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
  html_notebook: default
---

###Default Arrangement
```{r, echo=FALSE,message=FALSE, fig.height=4, fig.width=2, fig.show='hold'}
#devtools::install_github("wch/webshot")

library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(RColorBrewer)

m1 <- leaflet(quakes) %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852)

m2 <- leaflet(quakes) %>% 
        addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas") %>% 
        addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852)

m3 <- leaflet(quakes) %>%
        addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner") %>%
        addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852)
m1
m2
m3
```
````

If you want to have this format for both pdf and html output you could add this script to the body ofyour Rmd document (not inside a chunk):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.leaflet').css('float','left');
  });
</script>
```

Trying to add this CSS snippet via the chunk option `out.extra` does not work, since LaTeX does not know how to deal with CSS. Though the JS code is ignored when compiled to pdf.

[image]

Comment: This is precisely the PDF output I was look for! Unfortunately, now the HTML output displays the maps in stacked format. Is there a way to have the best of both worlds here (i.e., both pdf and html documents show the maps in a single-row arrangement)?

Comment: I gave it a shot. Updated my answer.

Comment: Add the script to the R chunk? To a js chunk?

Comment: FWIW, in `library(mapview)` we have functions `latticeView` to arrange multiple maps in lattice-like fashion and `sync` to synchronise multiple maps; see http://environmentalinformatics-marburg.github.io/mapview/sync/sync.html for examples. Will likely only work for the html document though.

Answer (score 3):

While the selected answer did resolve my problem, I have decided to take a slightly different approach.

I still adjust the CSS styling, but instead of using a JS script that targets all `.leaflet` elements, I passed each leaflet htmlwidget to a helper function called `styleWidget` that adjusts the CSS individually. This function is explained [here](http://widgets1092.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=61900561&last=1&item=19), but I'll add its definition below anyway:

```
styleWidget <- function(hw=NULL, style="", addl_selector="") {
        stopifnot(!is.null(hw), inherits(hw, "htmlwidget"))

        # use current id of htmlwidget if already specified
        elementId <- hw$elementId
        if(is.null(elementId)) {
                # borrow htmlwidgets unique id creator
                elementId <- sprintf(
                        'htmlwidget-%s',
                        htmlwidgets:::createWidgetId()
                )
                hw$elementId <- elementId
        }

        htmlwidgets::prependContent(
                hw,
                htmltools::tags$style(
                        sprintf(
                                "#%s %s {%s}",
                                elementId,
                                addl_selector,
                                style
                        )
                )
        )
}
```

This improves on Martin's solution because it gives more control – for instance, I can now change the third map's stye to `float: none;` so that the following elements aren't displayed beside the maps. The `styleWidget` function can be used to modify the CSS of *any* htmlwidget (although not Shiny widgets), making it a good general-purpose tool to have in the toolbox.