# Include Viewer-output in PDF

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

I have a R-Markdown file that includes some HTML-output that I want to knit to a pdf. My question is, is there a way of capturing the output of the Viewer and include it automatically.

For example, consider the following MWE:

````
---
title: "Include Viewer in PDF"
author: "Myself"
date: "today"
output:
  pdf_document: default
always_allow_html: yes
---
```{r}
library(stringr)
str_view("hello world", "o\\s[sw]")
```
````

If I use knit to HTML, the result is shown properly: 
[image: image1]

If I use knit to PDF, the result is not shown at all (because I used `always_allow_html: yes`, however if I exclude that specification, I get the error: 
`Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output. ...`):
[image: image2]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution. Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562947/how-to-arrange-html-widgets-inside-of-a-rmarkdown-document-pdf-html), which directed me towards the `webshot`-library.

So install `webshot` and run `webshot::install_phantomjs()` if necessary. Now knitr is able to take a screenshot of the Viewer automatically.

The PDF-code above now yields:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me. The output I get is really small, barely readable. Any way to control the output size?