# str_view() in pdf slides is no longer working

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, stringr

In the past, the html output from `str_view()` could be properly rendered in pdf slides, given that the `webshot` package was installed (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43440482/4303162)). However, this no longer works.

The following Rmd file should produce a title slide and a slide showing a regex example:

````
---
title: "Regex"
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(stringr)
```

## `str_view`

```{r regex1}
str_view(c("abc", "bcd", "cde"), "bc", html = TRUE)
```
````

If only the `webshot` package, but not `webshot2`, is installed, I get the following error on knitting:

```
Error:
! webshot.js returned failure value: 1
Backtrace:
  1. rmarkdown::render(...)
  2. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
  3. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
  7. knitr:::process_group.block(group)
  8. knitr:::call_block(x)
     ...
 19. knitr (local) value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible)
 20. knitr (local) fun(x, options = options)
 22. knitr::knit_print(x, ...)
 23. knitr:::html_screenshot(x)
 26. webshot (local) `<fn>`(...)
Execution halted
```

Calling `webshot::is_phantomjs_installed()` returns `TRUE`, so  PhantomJS is installed.

If I install `webshot2`, knitting works without error, but the html-output of `str_view()` is not shown:

[image]

The expected output that could be created in the past would look something like this (recreated with an image manipulation program):

[image]

What is the problem here? And is there still a way to get this to work?

(I am aware that I could use the text output from `str_view()` without `html = TRUE`, but I would prefer the html output.)

I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04.2 using the following versions:

- R 4.3.1
- Pandoc 3.1.1 (the version that comes with RStudio)
- webshot 0.5.5
- webshot2 0.1.0
- rmarkdown 2.23
- knitr 1.43
- stringr 1.5.0

Comment: can you include the version of webshot, stringr etc you are using? Because the code works for me

Comment: @Mark Does it work with webshot or webshot2? And you can see the htmI output? I have added the versions to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's actually using either, as (from what I understand) webshot and webshot2 create screenshots, and the output from knitting the file has highlightable text, which generally isn't the case with screenshots

Comment: @mark That's an excellent observation: also in my old slides, the text can be marked and copied. But on the other hand, I get an error message from webshot, when I knit with only webshot installed. Which of the two (webshot, webshot2) do you have installed?

Comment: I installed both

Comment: what happens when you try to run the code chunk without knitting?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgyTb.png after running the code, I get this

Comment: @Mark Me too, running `str_view()` in RStudio shows the rendered html in the Viewer as expected.

Comment: interesting/how odd! So it would appear that you are able to generate correct html. Okay, another test - what if you try knitting the html to another format? e.g. instead of making a beamer_presentation, knit to a pdf_document

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the new idea. Unfortunately, with pdf_document the result is the same: the code is shown, the output is empty. It really seems that this is a problem outside of R/knitr/rmarkdown. By the way, what system are you using? Mine is Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I'm using Mac, but I have a Windows PC I could try it out on. Could potentially download Ubuntu as well if needs be

Comment: @Mark Well, that seems a bit too much effort from your side. I also checked html_document and this works. Thanks for your help so far. I probably need someone who can reproduce the problem and solve it. I am really quite clueless what else I could try.

Comment: the one thing I can think of that could potentially give some leads is manually knitting the file. From what I understand, it's a multi-step process, and if you can figure out which part of it is not working, it should help get closer to the nub of the issue

Comment: I sometimes use VS Code, which I'm fairly sure uses it's own R installation, at least on Mac. You could try using that, and then see if you still get the same result. If you do, then you can rule out the R distribution or any of the individual packages you have.