# HTML widgets alignment in rmarkdwon

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I use the `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.align = "center")` at the beginning of the rmarkdown document to set the alignment of figures. When I output HTML files, the static figures are aligned to the center, but the HTML widgets, such as outputs from `leaflet()` and `ggplotly()` have the default alignment (to the left). Is there an option to force the HTML widgets to the center?

EDIT: example given below.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.align = "center")
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
```

```{r static plot}
# This is aligned to center

g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + 
geom_point()
g
```

```{r html widget}
# html output isn't aligned
p <- ggplotly(g)
p
```
````

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562947/how-to-arrange-html-widgets-inside-of-a-rmarkdown-document-pdf-html

Comment: While there may be a better way I usually use CSS to position HTML widgets.  If you post an example, I would be happy to demonstrate.

Comment: Updated with example.

Answer (score 0):

You could resize the plot to the default width of the document and then use some CSS:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

<style>
/* resize the widget container */
.plotly { 
  width: 100% !important;
}

/* center the widget */
div.svg-container {
  margin: auto !important;
}
</style>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.align = "center")
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
```


```{r static plot}
# This is aligned to center
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + 
geom_point()
g
```

```{r html widget}
p <- ggplotly(g, browser.fill = F) %>% 
  layout(autosize = F, width = '100%', height = '100%')
p
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While this solves my problem, I don't like the fact that I have to add some CSS codes at the beginning of the script and it's not very generalisable if I also have a leaflet map I want to adjust. Do you understand the `styleWidget` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39607828/4227151). I wish I could ask the author directly, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.