# Center leaflet in a rmarkdown document

Tags: html, css, r, leaflet, r-markdown

I want to create an html document with a centered leaflet widget inside it.

````
---
title: "Exemple"
author: "Antoine Bichat"
date: "31/08/2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r leaflet, fig.align="center"}
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
```
````

The first idea with `fig.align="center"` doesn't work.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458961/html-widgets-alignment-in-rmarkdwon) and I adapted it to my case:

```
<style>
/* resize the widget container */
.leaflet { 
  width: 80% !important;
}

/* center the widget */
div.leaflet-control-container {
  margin: auto !important;
}
</style>
```

but if I don't want to have an `out.width` of 100% (and I don't want to), it doesn't work.

Or maybe I did it wrong... 
Actually I prefer a 100% `R`/`Rmarkdown` solution but I'm open to everything :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the CSS code `margin: auto` for `.html-widget`

````
---
title: "Exemple"
author: "Antoine Bichat"
date: "31/08/2018"
output: html_document
---

<style>
.html-widget {
    margin: auto;
}
</style>

```{r leaflet, fig.align="center"}
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
```
````

[image]

That will center every htmlwidget. 
You can also put :

```
<style>
.leaflet {
    margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

For centering only the leaflet.

Comment: great answer! It works for tmap too which use leaflet dependencies